# Embedded Resource in ASP.NET from library

Tags: asp.net

Good day!
I have problem with ASP.NET
I create library and Embedded Resource to it. When I use this library in Console Application or Debug ASP.Net solution in Visual Studio 2010 everything ok. This resource finds. 
But when I try to published this ASP.NET solution in IIS. 
IIS get me 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find file 'test.txt'. at x28925c9b27b37a46.x220f433da4115056.xde6236852622c268(String x1c1fc72fe1a3b4ea, Assembly x39e0a96279c40baa) at x28925c9b27b37a46.x220f433da4115056.x7d0214bf69711dd9(String x1c1fc72fe1a3b4ea, Assembly x5807f920b6fc67c4) at AsposeLicenseTest._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\test\TestCase\AsposeLicenseTest\Default.aspx.vb:line 9
What will me do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've run into the problem described here

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/313503/setlicense-system.nullreferenceexception.aspx